# Haskell Lucid OverloadedString

Tags: string, haskell

I'm using Lucid in a small Scotty project.

In below program:

```
p_ "hello world"
```

I want to run some string functions such as:

```
p_ (reverse "hello world")
```

Of course I got a type error.

Could anyone help how I can make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the [**`fromString :: IsString s => String -> s`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-String.html#v:fromString) conversion yourself, which is basically what [**`OverloadedStrings`** [ghc-doc]](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-OverloadedStrings) does for you. For example:

```
import Data.String(fromString)

p_ (fromString (reverse "hello world"))
```

If you enable `OverloadedStrings`, then you could say that the compiler implicitly uses a `fromString` for each string *literal*, here we will make the conversion ourself explicitly.

Given that here `"hello world"` is (likely) a [**`Text`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.0/docs/Data-Text.html#t:Text), you can do the reversing in the `Text` world:

```
{-# OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.Text as T

p_ (T.reverse "hello world")
```